# Does GORM has issue with field starts with max prefix or issue with Float field

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

i have a domain class that contains two fields : `minscale`, and `maxscale` :

```
class TeamRuleAverageStatic extends TeamRule {
    Float minscale; 
    Float maxscale;

}
```

*
i persist a record in database with `minscale=0.5` and `maxscale=0.9`

And when i tried to query it , i don't get anything  :

```
TeamRuleAverageStatic.findByMinscaleAndMaxscale(new Float(0.5),new Float(0.9));
```

I make another attempt , but without embedding maxscale :

```
 TeamRuleAverageStatic.findByMinscale(new Float(0.5));
```

So i get the expected result .

i try also :

```
     TeamRule.executeQuery('from TeamRule cu where cu.maxscale = ? and cu.minscale= ?', [new Float(0.9),new Float(0.5)])
// As TeamRule is the class mother of TeamRuleAverageStatic
```

Issue persists yet . 
it seems that `MAXSCALE` is a keyword or fields that start with the prefix 'max' , because query by the `MINSCALE` field works perfectly

**UPDATE:**

i do best practices with SQL query manually using `phphmyadmin` as GUI,

i get the same problem .

When i change the type of field to `Double` it works ! **WEIRD**

Reallly, it is the strange IT issue that meets me . 
What is the problem with `FLOAT` type ?

Comment: that's weird. Which DB are you using? Can you find out the sql queries executed against the DB and post those here? thanks.

Comment: MySQL DB . yes, i try with SQL query and the same pb is . it seems a SQL issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is cause by the nature of representation `float` and `double` values.
Both are used to represent floating point numbers, where `float` is for single-precision and `double` is for double-precision numbers.

MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values and eight bytes for double-precision values.

As from the [MySql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html):

> Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems.

You could try to use `decimal` instead of `float` or `double` because `decimal` is represented as strings internally to guarantee an exact precision.